# How to change the background image of Floating Action Button programatically in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I use the following `FloatingActionButton` and I have set the background image using `xml`. How can I change the image programmatically in Kotlin? I want to replace the image 'image-color' with 'image-bw'.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/image_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image-color"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:maxImageSize="56dp"
    app:tint="@null"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"
    android:contentDescription="Categories" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setImageDrawable` function.

```kotlin
imageFab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_drawable))
```

Comment: IIRC you can also use `imageFab.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable)`